# Efficient method of merging two neighboring indicies in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

What would be a most efficient method of merging two neighboring indicies in Scala? What I have in mind a nasty while loops with copying.

For example, there's a buffer array A, with length N. The new array need be generated such that for `A(i) = A(i) + A(i+1)`, where `i < N`

For example, merging and summing the second and third element, and generate a new array.
`ArrayBuffer(1,2,4,3) => ArrayBuffer(1,6,3)`

UPDATE:
I think I come up with some solution, but doesn't like it much. Any suggestion to improve would be highly appreciated.

`scala> val i = 1
i: Int = 1`

`scala> ArrayBuffer(1,2,4,3).zipWithIndex.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer[Int]())( (k,v)=> if(v._2==i+1){ k(k.length-1) =(k.last+v._1);k; }else k+= v._1 )`

Comment: Why `(1,6,3)` and not `(3,6,7)`?

Comment: It should merge and sum only neighboring indices, the case when it's the first and last element is not interesting. The challenge for me to merge indices in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get neighbors is to use `sliding` method.

```
a.sliding(2, 1).map(_.sum)
```

where the first argument is a size and the second one is step.

If you want to keep the first and the last element intact something like this should work:

```
a.head +: a.drop(1).dropRight(1).sliding(2, 1).map(_.sum).toArray :+ a.last
```

If you want to avoid copying and array on append/prepend you can rewrite it as follows:

```
val aa = a.sliding(2, 1).map(_.sum).toArray
aa(0) = a.head
aa(aa.size - 1) = a
```

or use [ListBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer) which provides constant time prepend and append.

It should be also possible to use `Iterators`:

```
val middle: Iterator[Int] = a.drop(1).dropRight(1).sliding(2, 1).map(_.sum)
(Iterator(a.head) ++ middle ++ Iterator(a.last)).toArray // or toBuffer
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion! What's running time of the solution? Is it O(N)? I update a description with foldLeft suggestion, however I doesn't really like it.

Comment: It is O(N), although `+:` and `:+` returns a copy of array which is not optimal. If you prefer to avoid that you can split it like this: `val aa = a.sliding(2, 1).map(_.sum).toArray; aa(0) = a.head; aa(aa.size - 1) = a.last` or use `ListBuffer` which provides both `append` and prepend in a constant time.